# MySQL query greatly slows down on longer date ranges. Why?

Tags: mysql

I am looking for help on how to make the following query more efficient. Currently, it works but it is not efficient after the week range is increased past a week or two.

I am posting the query for now but please let me know if you need additional info.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b7046/1)

EXPLAIN result

```
id select_type        table type  possible_keys key     key_len ref    rows Extra
 1 PRIMARY            u     const PRIMARY       PRIMARY 8       const  1    Using temporary; Using filesort
 1 PRIMARY            A     ALL   (NULL)        (NULL) (NULL)   (NULL) 9    Using where
 1 PRIMARY            B     ALL   (NULL)        (NULL) (NULL)   (NULL) 9    Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
 3 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY C     ALL   (NULL)        (NULL) (NULL)   (NULL) 9    Using where
```

Basically, this is a clock app.

The user clocks in by selecting a project & task.

This record is then inserted into tbl_user_time_log with a date/time stamp.

**Overview**

When the user clocks into same project & different task, yet another clock record with date/time stamp is created.

So long as this "most current time punch" isn't a clock out, this query is now able to calculate the total time different between previous clock punch to current clock punch.

It will proceed to calculate in pairs of stamps until clock out is reached and if there is more than one clock out within the same day.

```
SELECT USER_ID,
u.USE_TYPE,
u.USE_FIRST_NAME,
u.USE_LAST_NAME,
UTL_ACTIVITY,
UTL_EVENT,
UTL_TASK,
u.USE_PAY_RATE,
SUM(UTL_DURATION) AS UTL_DURATION_TOTAL       
FROM (

SELECT A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID,
A.CLIENT_ID,
A.PROJECT_ID,
A.USER_ID,
A.UTL_DTSTAMP,
/* DATE_FORMAT(A.UTL_DTSTAMP,'%H:%i:%s') AS UTL_DTSTAMP, */
A.UTL_LATITUDE,
A.UTL_LONGITUDE,
A.UTL_ACTIVITY,
A.UTL_EVENT,
A.UTL_TASK,
/* DURATION in seconds  */
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, A.UTL_DTSTAMP, B.UTL_DTSTAMP) AS UTL_DURATION
FROM   tbl_user_time_log A
/* Alias table (B) begins... */
INNER JOIN tbl_user_time_log B 
/* Inner Join First condition */
ON B.UTL_DTSTAMP = (
/* Inner Join > Inner Select */
/* Magical... */
SELECT 
MIN(UTL_DTSTAMP) 
/* Alias table (C) begins... */
FROM tbl_user_time_log C 
/* Alias table (C) condition(s)... */
WHERE 
C.USER_ID = A.USER_ID 
AND C.UTL_DTSTAMP > A.UTL_DTSTAMP
) 
/* Inner Join Second condition */
AND B.USER_ID = A.USER_ID 
/* Derived table (1) condition(s)... */
WHERE  A.USER_ID = '465617'
/* Between current pay period Start date and Current pay period end date */
/* First day of the week is Monday.*/
-- AND DATE(A.UTL_DTSTAMP) = CURDATE()
AND ( A.UTL_DTSTAMP BETWEEN '2019-07-22 00:00:00' AND '2019-07-29 23:59:59' )
/* Filter out Clock Out. */
AND A.UTL_EVENT <> 'CLOCK OUT'

/* Our derived table... */
) AS tbl_derived_1

INNER JOIN tbl_user u ON u.PK_USER_ID = tbl_derived_1.USER_ID

GROUP BY USER_ID, UTL_TASK
ORDER BY u.USE_FIRST_NAME ASC, UTL_TASK ASC;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. In addition, as well as the SHOW CREATE TABLE statements mentioned in the link above, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: Got it! i will be posting an updated version once I get home. Thank you!

Comment: No rush; we're here all week.

Comment: SQL Fiddle posted.

Comment: That is one heluva commute. You still haven't provided the EXPLAIN (incidentally, I quite like to use the `\G` delimiter with EXPLAIN, instead of `;`)

Comment: HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA. Oh man... I almost fell off the chair.

Comment: Alright. Added an explanation I hope is useful to all.

Comment: That's not what an EXPLAIN is! An EXPLAIN is the result of `EXPLAIN [YOUR QUERY HERE]`

Comment: Wow.. sorry about that. EXPLAIN posted.

Comment: Also, you have no usable index on tbl_user_time_log. At the very least, you should have a composite index on `(USER_ID,UTL_DTSTAMP)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering only tbl_derived_1 for now,  I wonder if the following a) returns the same result as your derived table, and b) does so more optimally?

```
   SELECT a.pk_user_time_log_id
        , a.client_id
        , a.project_id
        , a.user_id
        , a.utl_dtstamp
        , a.utl_latitude
        , a.utl_longitude
        , a.utl_activity
        , a.utl_event
        , a.utl_task
        , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.utl_dtstamp, MIN(b.utl_dtstamp)) utl_duration
     FROM tbl_user_time_log a
     JOIN tbl_user_time_log b
       ON b.user_id = a.user_id
      AND b.utl_dtstamp > a.utl_dtstamp
    WHERE a.user_id = 465605
      AND a.utl_dtstamp BETWEEN '2019-08-19 00:00:00' AND '2019-08-25 23:59:59'
      AND a.utl_event <> 'clock out'
    GROUP
       BY a.pk_user_time_log_id
        , a.client_id
        , a.project_id
        , a.user_id
        , a.utl_dtstamp
        , a.utl_latitude
        , a.utl_longitude
        , a.utl_activity
        , a.utl_event
        , a.utl_task;
```

Comment: Strawberry, what else would I remove in order to get a report for all user ids instead of just one? If I remove `a.user_id = 465605` from the `WHERE` clause, will the query still remain coherent?

Comment: Yes. Because a.user_id is in the SELECT and the GROUP BY

Comment: Ok. I now need to run a report that selects the totals for each task in each user pay period. Is it possible to turn this query into a sum withough killing performance?

Comment: You're welcome to ask a new question, referencing this one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to SUM this now inner-query results by USER_ID & UTL_TASK. Reference only.

```
SELECT USER_ID,
       UTL_TASK,
       SUM(UTL_DURATION) AS DURATION_TOTAL       
  FROM (

SELECT a.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID,
         a.CLIENT_ID,
         a.PROJECT_ID,
         a.USER_ID,
         a.UTL_PAY_RATE,
         a.UTL_DTSTAMP,
         a.UTL_LATITUDE,
         a.UTL_LONGITUDE,
         a.UTL_ACTIVITY,
         a.UTL_EVENT,
         a.UTL_TASK,
         a.UTL_DESCRIPTION,
         TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.UTL_DTSTAMP, MIN(b.UTL_DTSTAMP)) AS UTL_DURATION
FROM tbl_user_time_log a
JOIN tbl_user_time_log b
    ON b.USER_ID = a.USER_ID
        AND b.UTL_DTSTAMP > a.UTL_DTSTAMP
WHERE a.UTL_DTSTAMP
    BETWEEN '2019-08-12 00:00:00'
        AND '2019-08-18 23:59:59'
        AND a.UTL_EVENT <> 'CLOCK OUT'
GROUP BY  a.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID, a.CLIENT_ID, a.PROJECT_ID, a.USER_ID, a.UTL_DTSTAMP, a.UTL_LATITUDE, a.UTL_LONGITUDE, a.UTL_ACTIVITY, a.UTL_EVENT, a.UTL_TASK
ORDER BY  a.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID ASC

) AS tbl_derived_1

GROUP BY USER_ID, UTL_TASK
ORDER BY USER_ID ASC;
```